# calculating alpha & power centralities by igraph

Tags: r

I was calculating alpha and power centralities for a graph by igraph package but I got this error

```
alpha.cent<-alpha_centrality(graph,loops = F)
    Error in .local(a, b, ...) : 
      cs_lu(A) failed: near-singular A (or out of memory)
pow.cent<-power_centrality(graph,loops = F)
Error in .local(a, b, ...) : 
      cs_lu(A) failed: near-singular A (or out of memory)
```

Does anyone know what does it mean? and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether this solves your exact problem as you did not provide sample data, but I had the same problem and solved it by playing around with the option `exponent = [...]`. The igraph vignette also suggest to try values ranging from -1 to 1 in 0.1 steps.

These 2 websites/papers discuss the beta value of the power centrality (which is the exponent in the igraph formula) in a bit more detail:

https://www.cmu.edu/joss/content/articles/volume12/Rodan.pdf
http://www.faculty.ucr.edu/~hanneman/nettext/C10_Centrality.html

**EDIT**

Another potential source for errors could be isolated vertices. To check whether you have such and delete them you can do the following:

```
sum(degree(g) < 1) # if value is non-zero you have isolates
gg <- delete_vertices(g, which(degree(g) < 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to able to avoid the:

```
  cs_lu(A) failed: near-singular A (or out of memory)
```

errors and get both power_centrality and alpha_centrality working by modifying the exponent (which JNWHH suggested) and alpha options respectively.

```
power_centrality <- power_centrality(g, exponent = 0.9)

alpha_centrality <- alpha_centrality(g, alpha=0.9)
```